# Samba is faster than NFS when accessing from Mac, any reason

Tags: ubuntu, networking, nfs, mac, server-message-block

Refer to this question (closed): [Sharing folder from Linux to Mac, Samba or NFS?](https://serverfault.com/questions/460795/sharing-folder-from-linux-to-mac-samba-or-nfs), most people suggested that NFS is faster and therefore I did a quick test:

- MacBook Pro / OSX Lion
- Ubuntu 12.04 inside VirtualBox (host only network)

On the Ubuntu VM install default samba and nfs server (resvport option is used for nfs client).

**Test1: a folder of 1640 files (total 34M)**

NFS: 2m16.760s

SMB: 0m43.772s

**Test1: a single compressed file of 90M**

NFS: 0m5.699s

SMB: 0m2.483s

As you can see, both SMB is performing much faster, are there any reason or anything I have missed during the configuration?

Comment: This is not a valid observation unless you provide much more detailed information on how you tested it.  For example, if you did not clear the UNIX buffer cache before each test you can be easily mislead by running simple tests.  There are many many more questions here.  In fact, benchmarking is an art itself.  Thus the answers you receive for this type of question will be mostly speculation with the lack of test setup and harness information.

Comment: You should describe how did you do your test. Did you test always in a same order, for example - NFS first? Which software have you used? This may clarify what happened.